# Unix: Why it suggested to create users for some applications?

Tags: unix

Is it some kind of encapsulation when by some tutorials I am suggested creating separate `unix` user.

**E.g.** in [tomcat installation instructions](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-on-linux-installation-and-configuration) it said:

> 1 - Create a Low Privilege User
>
> Running Tomcat as root introduces the unnecessary risk that a
>   compromised Tomcat instance could yield control over your entire
>   server.  Thus, creating a user with low privileges to run Tomcat
>   should be standard practice when installing new instances.

**Question:**

1. Is it single reason? What about installation under my `sudoer` user, not `root`.
2. What about different installation managers like [Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew), how do they solve this problem?

Comment: When you use sudo you are tempararily root. Follow the guides and use a separate user for tomcat.

Comment: It is a general rule. If you are root you can do whatever you want to the system and, more important, even whatever you do __not__ want. So to protect the system from desired (malware) and unwanted problems you can create a standard user, that can _do mess_ only for what it is allowed to the standard users.  (So in theory you couldn't be able to dismantle a complete system for one error). Sudo allows to an instance of a program launched by a user, to run as root and again to do all that root can do, that means all. Do a separate user :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user, except root, has access to the files and directories they own, but limited access to most other resources.  This is used to minimize the capability of any one user to compromise services run by other users.  By having a separate user for each application you limit the ability to compromise your system but exploiting an application.  Without this separation of ownership, your entire system is only as secure as your least secure service. If an service runs as root, your whole system is open to compromise if that service is compromised.

It is best practice to have the web content and configuration owned by a user other than one used to run the web server.  This limits the ability to add malware to a site by compromising the web server.  If necessary, the web server may be able to write to a dedicated directory tree used for upload.  The web server should be configured not to execute content from the upload directory.

It is common for the related SMTP server and POP/IMAP server to run as different users.  The prevents a compromise of the POP/IMAP server from being used to modify the SMTP server's configuration.